# Multiple Error Handling on Python

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

I was wondering how I would handle multiple errors on python.

For example:

The user enters an integer between 0 and 9. If the integer is out of range then the program will say so and ask for another input until a valid input is obtained. If the input is not an integer then the program will say it is an invalid input and ask for another input until a valid input is obtained. Finally, if no input is provided, then the program would say there needs to be an input, and ask for another input until a valid input is obtained. These three errors must be distinguished for a single input variable.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Have you tried an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate user input against several criteria and keep asking for new input if any of them are failed, you probably want a loop that keeps going until you have a valid result:

```
result = None
while result is None:
    input_str = input("Enter an integer between 0 and 9:")
    if input_str == "":
        print("An empty input is not valid.")
    else:
        try:
            result = int(input_str)
            if not 0 <= result <= 9:
                print("That number out of bounds.")
                result = None
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not an integer.")

# do stuff with result here
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help:

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    in_val = input("Enter an integer: ")
    if not in_val:
        print("No input was given, please try again.")
        continue

    try:
        in_num = int(in_val)

        if in_num < 0 or in_num > 9:
            print("The value entered is out of the valid range (0-9).")
            continue
        valid = True
    except ValueError:
        print("The value entered was not a number, try again.")
        continue
```

Comment: I don't think it's clear the OP was asking about command line options, so this may be a great deal of overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of this:

```
wrong = True
while wrong:
        num = input("Enter a number between 0 and 9: ")
        if not num:
                print("Please enter valid input.")
                continue

        try:
                num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
                print("Please enter valid input.")
                continue

        if num < 0 or num > 9:
                print("Please enter a number between 0 and 9.")
                continue

        wrong = False

print(num)
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$
Enter a number between 0 and 9: 
Please enter valid input.
Enter a number between 0 and 9: 
Please enter valid input.
Enter a number between 0 and 9: hhello
Please enter valid input.
Enter a number between 0 and 9: 90
Please enter a number between 0 and 9.
Enter a number between 0 and 9: -2324
Please enter a number between 0 and 9.
Enter a number between 0 and 9: aisjdo93rwfeljks
Please enter valid input.
Enter a number between 0 and 9: 5
5
```